# Компиляция приложения android на сервере

Tags: java, android, сервер

Как перенести процесс сборки проекта на отдельную машину? поверхностный гугл не дал внятных результатов. Кто связывался с этим? пишу в AS

Comment: вопрос слишком общий. Фактически вам нужно сделать git pull (как угодно, хоть sh скриптом), потом ./gradlew assembleRelease. Потом выгрузить собранную apk и/или лог сборки.

Comment: @pavel зачем городить собственный велосипед, если уже давно есть для этих целей инструменты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите что такое Continius Integration. Можно использовать например TimCity Jankins установленные на локальную машину. Можно использовать облачные CI. Например Cycle CI. Или [GreenHouseCI](https://greenhouseci.com/). GreenHouseCI вообще простая. Ей просто нужно указать ваш репозиторий и при каждом pull будет происходить сборка. Можно настроить рассылку на почту и в slack уведомлений о новой сборке

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите в сторону такие продуктов, как [jenkins](https://jenkins.io) или [teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

С их помощью можно настроить автоматическую сборку и наладить процесс `continious integration`

Так же, если у вас нет выделенного сервера, можно воспользоваться сервисом [travis ci](https://travis-ci.org)